# Notifications are not grouped in iOS 12

Tags: notifications, ios

According to the WWDC 2018 Apple Keynote, iOS 12 has brought notification improvements since now message threads and notification topics are grouped together.

[image]

Nevertheless, I have noticed that, sometimes, notifications generated from the same app (e.g., from Gmail or Facebook Messenger) still appear "one under the other" and are not collectively stacked on the home screen as they should be supposed to. How should I fix this issue?

Comment: Can you go to `Settings -> Notifications` and find that app.  Tap it and scroll down to `Notification Grouping`.  What does it indicate?

Comment: @fsb It says "Automatic"

Comment: `Automatic` means iOS will group them but it will often create a separate notification for emails from different senders.  If you choose `By App` it will stack according to the app each time.  Try that and see if it helps.

Comment: @fsb no way, for Gmail, although choosing the “By App” option, I’m still experiencing the same issue.

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned some email apps treat alerts from different senders as separate notifications so that could happen.  Hopefully, the app or iOS receives an update to fix that.